# Refresh CardMedia aspect ratio when using css transform rotate

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an image upload form that displays the uploaded image in CardMedia component, then you can rotate the image using css transform rotate (the initial rotation will then occur on the server). Although CardMedia is responsive when the image is rendered, the aspect ratio does not adjust when doing the rotation. The result is when the image is for example rotated 90° the image doesn't fit in the CardMedia.

Any idea how to refresh the CardMedia component when I push the rotation button so the CardMedia aspect ratio is corrected?

I have attached a small demo showing this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-cardmedia-imageupload-with-rotate-ov4tj?file=/demo.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import {
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardMedia,
  CardActions,
  Grid
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      }
    },
    input: {
      display: "none"
    }
  })
);

export default function UploadButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);

  const handleUploadClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    setImage(imageUrl);
  };

  const handleRotation = () => {
    let newValue = rotation + 90 >= 360 ? 0 : rotation + 90;
    setRotation(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2} >
          <Grid>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
              <CardActionArea>
                {image ? (
                  <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    image={image}
                    style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)` }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    alt="Contemplative Reptile"
                    image="https://via.placeholder.com/300"
                    title="placeholder image"
                  />
                )}
              </CardActionArea>
              <CardActions>
                <input
                  accept="image/*"
                  className={classes.input}
                  id="contained-button-file"
                  multiple
                  type="file"
                  onChange={e => {
                    if (e.target.files !== null) {
                      handleUploadClick(e);
                    }
                  }}
                />
                <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
                    Upload
                  </Button>
                </label>
                {image && (
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={() => handleRotation()}
                  >
                    Rotate
                  </Button>
                )}
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

1. Upload any image with different aspect ratio other than placeholder image
2. Push "Rotate" button

Thanks in advance!